# CasperJS and alert boxes

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, phantomjs, casperjs

How do I test that an alert box on my page was called? Can I grab the text of the alert box and evaluate it?

My click in CasperJS is done like this:

```
casper.waitForSelector('a[href="javascript:UserLogin()"]',
    function success() {
        this.test.comment("Submiting the bad login info");
        this.test.assertExists('a[href="javascript:UserLogin()"]');
        this.click("a#h_login");
    },
    function fail() {
        this.test.assertExists('a[href="javascript:UserLogin()"]');
});
```

The UserLogin function checks and in this case, returns this:

```
alert('Login has failed.');
```

How do I check this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to listen to the `remote.alert` [event](http://casperjs.org/events-filters.html):

```
casper.on('remote.alert', function(message) {
    this.echo('alert message: ' + message);
    // or if you want to test it
    this.test.assertMatch(message, /Login has failed/);
});
```

An attempt to make it a bit more *synchronous*:

```
function testAlert(message) {
    this.test.assertMatch(message, /Login has failed/);
}

casper.then(function() {
    // temporarily registering listener
    this.on('remote.alert', testAlert);
});

casper.waitForSelector('#login', function success() {
    this.test.pass('selector was found');
    this.click("#login");
}, function fail() {
    this.test.fail('selector was found');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.removeListener('remote.alert', testAlert);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Version 1.1-beta4 provides the [`casper.waitForAlert` function](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforalert). With it you can write nicer tests when you need to react to different alerts on the page.